# How can i make a redirect in django template tag?

Tags: django

I have one custom template tag function.

I try raise custom exception and catch it in custom middleware, but template engine process exception and raise TemplateSyntaxError.

Comment: Show us your template code, your custom middleware code, and the error message shown, and someone *might* be able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the template engine runs before your response/post-rendering middleware, and is not tolerant of exceptions in template tags -- and nor should it be. How would it know there's middleware waiting in the response cycle that will catch it?

The simplest way forward is probably to pre-check in the view for the condition that would cause the template tag to explode (not seeing any code, I don't know whether this is really possible) and issue a suitable HttpResponse/exception handling change of flow there.

Comment: Unfortunately, views knows about template tag nothing. Tag contents isolated logic.

Comment: If the tag deals with variables that are provided in the view. Can you not check those variables there? If you post some code, we might be able to see what you want to do and help more